# Atomic block in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to do an atomic read and add in CUDA 8

```
__device__ int counter = 5;
__global__ void prime()
{
    int num = counter;
    atomicAdd(&counter, 1);
    //......<rest of the code>......
}
```

atomicAdd() takes care of the add operation. But all my threads read the same value before increment.
I want a thread to read, increment then another thread to do the same.
Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: `int num = atomicAdd(&counter, 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicadd), `atomicAdd` can return the previous value of the variable being atomically updated. So as pointed out in comments, your kernel could be re-written as

```
__device__ int counter = 5;
__global__ void prime()
{
    int num = atomicAdd(&counter, 1);
    //......<rest of the code>......
}
```

meaning that `num` will be assigned the existing value of `counter` before the `atomicAdd` operation is performed.